# Does an IIS web garden use threads or processes?

Tags: multithreading, iis, web, process, web-garden

When you set an application pool's Maximum Worker Processes attribute in IIS are you actually setting the number of processes or the number of threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are processes (w3wp instances). Each process will have multiple threads.

[ASP.NET Web Garden - How Many Worker Processes Do I Need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151251/asp-net-web-garden-how-many-worker-processes-do-i-need)