# Access session variable in Session_End

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Hi
in my web app users login to website normally and they have tagged in user table in database as online user in Session_End i want to log them out
In Session_End i have no access to HttpContext.Current.Session or Session only
they are both null how can i access to session variable at (Session_End) event.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using InProc Session (so the Session_End event fires) you can use

```
this.Session
```

When you're using the global.Asax, Global.asax itself extends HttpApplication

From MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx):

> "This class is the base class for applications that are defined by the
>   user in the Global.asax file."

I created a method inside Global.asax that returns the Session:

```
public HttpSessionState GetSession()
{
    //Check if current context exists
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session;
    }
    else
    {
        return this.Session;
    }
}
```

So I can use the following method @global.asax:

```
var x = GetSession()["key"];
```

**Edit**

However, multiple application instances can be generated to handle requests (you can set how many worker processes you want in

`IIS > App Pools > Properties`

But with different Worker Process the request can fall on one of many worker processes that won't have the session information that you want

See [ASP.NET session state and multiple worker processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147578/asp-net-session-state-and-multiple-worker-processes)

I would suggest storing the first access abd the last registered access ([Post_Authenticate event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postauthorizerequest.aspx)).

In addition use a SQL Server job running periodically to check the last access. This way you can prevent your app crashing (when the Session_End event wouldn't fire).

Answer (score 1):

Session_End only works if you're using InProc session management. Maybe you're using StateServer or SqlServer approach?