# ASP Classic : Can not clear session after increase worker process

Tags: session, iis, asp-classic

I call `Session.Contents.RemoveAll()`, but this does not work when we increase worker process (web garden).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET session state and multiple worker processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147578/asp-net-session-state-and-multiple-worker-processes) May reference ASP.Net but it still applies.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use more than one worker process, you cannot reliably use the InProc session state.

See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147578/asp-net-session-state-and-multiple-worker-processes) for more inforamtion.

Comment: Just close/flag it as a dup and move on.